# PHP time difference class return different time difference

Tags: php, mysql

Please i need help on this code. Am trying to get the time difference between a time in my database and 48hours ahead. What i want is the difference in the time a data was logged into my database and 48hours ahead. So this is like a countdown to 48hours ahead.

For example i logged a data into my database at this time 2017-10-18 02:49:25 in my database.

At times it returns 2 hours below the result am expecting.

```
$date = '2017-10-18 02:49:25';

$date1 = new DateTime($date.' A');   
$date1->modify('+2 day'); //am trying to get 48 hours ahead of the time in my DB  
$tomorrowDATE = $date1->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');

$starttimestamp = strtotime($date);
$endtimestamp = strtotime($tomorrowDATE);

//Here am getting time difference in hours between when the data was logged 
into my DB and current time of the day  
$currenttime = round(abs(strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s A')) - $starttimestamp)/3600);

$difference = round(abs($endtimestamp - $starttimestamp)/3600);
print $difference - $currenttime . 'hour left';
```

Comment: I do not see the code.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Try reading this http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php .

Comment: I have tried it but am not getting the correct time difference in hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you started using DateTime, but then reverted to not using it.  You could use DateTime for the entire thing:

```
<?php

# Change accordingly
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');

# Time in database
$readfromdb = '2017-10-24 02:49:25 A';
$datedb = new DateTime($readfromdb);

$datedbplus48 = new DateTime($readfromdb);
$datedbplus48->modify('+2 day');

$datenow = new DateTime();      # default to now

$difference = $datedbplus48->diff($datenow);

echo "<pre>\n";
echo "DATEDB      ";
    echo $datedb->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
echo "\nDATEPLUS48  ";
    echo $datedbplus48->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
echo "\nDATENOW     ";
    echo $datenow->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
echo "\nDIFF        ";
    echo $difference->days * 24 + $difference->format('%H');
echo "</pre>\n";

?>
```

I assume that:

- readfromdb: time of the insert, done before now()
- datedb: Datetime object for readfromdb
- datedbplus48: readfromdb + 48h
- datenow: current time
- difference: datedbplus48 - datenow
- Output is the difference in hours.

Results:

```
DATEDB      2017-10-24 02:49:25
DATEPLUS48  2017-10-26 02:49:25
DATENOW     2017-10-24 09:03:40
DIFF        36
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please i ran your code and it is returning 48 hours time difference. Which is 48 hours ahead of the logged time. But i need to do a countdown to that 48 hours. Currently it is showing 48 hours now. An hour from now it should show 47 hours and so forth until  it has gotten to 48 hours. That is what i want to achieve with my code.

Comment: Hi, $date->diff will still work,  you just have to define 2 things.  What is the end DateTime and the DateTime form the database and use the code above to ->diff between the two.

Comment: $hourleft = $datedb->diff(new DateTime($dateplus48->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')));

print $hourleft->h;

Comment: What I suggest is to accept this answer and post your new code in a new question.  Please make sure you detail how you define the end DateTime.  That is the crucial factor here.  You have the DateTime form the database, that one is ok.  But I am still uncertain how you set the end DateTime.

Comment: My endtime is 2days from the time i logged into database. Which gives me 48 hours interval. I took the time difference between my current local time and the time logged in to the database to get hours ago and subtract it from the 48 hours gotten before from the endtime

Comment: ah ok, so:    start = DB, end = DB + 48, you want end - now?

Comment: Exactly what i want, that way i can get the countdown. Here is what i really want to achieve. A person is given 48 hours from now to do a task. I want to display a countdown to tell him how much time he has left to do the task.

Comment: I edited the answer with that requirement, check it out.

Comment: Thanks alot i will implement it. Please is there any way i can reach you anytime i want to

Comment: Right here, I am connected almost every day :-)  Or others can help.

Comment: How do i contact you directly here

Comment: Hi you dont :-) post your questions, trust me there are better PHP guys on this site than I.

Answer (score 0):

> You will get time difference using mysql query
>   For Example.
>
> ```
> $set_waiting_time_val ="set time"; like as current time ,now()
> SELECT user_lastlogin, TIMEDIFF( user_lastlogin,$set_waiting_time_val ) AS last_login_time
> FROM user_login
> ```
>
> You also convert into hours

```
SELECT user_lastlogin, TIME_FORMAT( ABS( TIMEDIFF( user_lastlogin, now( ) ) ) , '%H hours' ) AS last_login_time
FROM user_login
```